# How to build x64 with monodevelop?

Tags: mono, 64-bit, monodevelop

I would like to build a x64 package of a project I wrote in monodevelop. I can change the project compiler options from x86 to x64, but if I do this, I get the error:

```
Error CS0016: Could not write to file `AudioCuesheetEditor', cause: AMD64 (CS0016) (AudioCuesheetEditor)
```

How can I build packages for x64 systems?

Thank you for help!

Comment: They probably didn't implement an "only run on x64, never on x86" option.  There is very little value to it.  Check if it has something similar to the AnyCPU option.

Comment: Thanks, with "any cpu" set in compiler options, I have been able to build. But what exactly does "any cpu" mean? Does this mean, mono runtime determines, which runtime will be used or something else?

Comment: Roughly.  You'll get x64 on a 64-bit operating system, x86 on a 32-bit operating system.  Automagic provided by the just-in-time compiler.

Comment: Well, any cpu works only on linux I now examined. If I try to start the build executable under windows, the application crashes and thats it. Any idea, why?

Comment: I found the answer myself. On windows x86 with anycpu there is no problem. Using windows x64 will crash becaus gtk-sharp has no x64 build.So on windows x64 you have to build x86.

Comment: Hmm, no.  The question is about a compile error, you are talking about a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `any cpu` configuration

You'll get x64 on a 64-bit operating system, x86 on a 32-bit operating system. Automagic provided by the just-in-time compiler.

**BUT** On windows x86 with anycpu there is no problem. Using windows x64 will crash becaus gtk-sharp has no x64 build. So on windows x64 you have to build x86.

Comment: I found the answer myself. On windows x86 with anycpu there is no problem. Using windows x64 will crash becaus gtk-sharp has no x64 build.So on windows x64 you have to build x86.

Comment: updated the answer!! rock on! Luckily my employer's software app doesn't support 32-bit windows *whew*

Comment: actually - no. I am building using msbuild on linux and when I run it on windows, the exe's are 32-bit. how can I make it build 64-bit?

Comment: i have a feeling you need to go into Project Options -> Build -> Compiler -> and set platform target to x64.