# How can I make 64bit gtk-sharp mono application for linux?

Tags: mono

I wonder if gtk-sharp 2 or 3 doesn't support 64bit programming on Linux?

```
mcs helloworld.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
file helloworld.exe
```

produces output like below:

```
helloworld.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

if I run helloworld.exe with mono on Ubuntu, would it run as 32bit program?
Doesn't gtk-sharp support 64bit program?

Comment: Try to avoid using `mcs` directly, as writing an MSBuild project file and then calling `msbuild` to compile is the common practice. To control the bitness of output files, you need to set the CPU target, https://manpages.debian.org/testing/mono-mcs/mcs.1.en.html#platform:ARCH

Comment: This QnA helpped me also -     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903884/how-to-build-x64-with-monodevelop

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the tips. I learned from you..